# Size command in linux

Tags: linux

What exactly does the size command (sans any flags) return in linux? if we are using a compiled assembler sourcecode, will this return the size useded by the program?

many thanks

Comment: what does "man size" say?

Comment: The question would be more convincing if you said you had already tried `man size` and didn't understand something in the information provided. As it is, the best answer is repeating the information from the man page.

Comment: lol, man size... almost as humorous as touch me

Comment: sorry, i did try man size - and ive tried it witha number of complied programs "size - list section sizes and total size. " is from the manual, but i cant make much headway with determining what this is measuring.

thanks

Comment: The command "man elf" will give you more information on object internal format. If it looks involved and complicated, it is.

Answer (score 7):

From the man page:

> The GNU size utility lists the section sizes---and the total size---for each of the object or archive files *objfile* in its argument list.  By default, one line of output is generated for each object file or each module in an archive.

Here's an example output from running `size foo.static`

```
   text    data     bss      dec    hex filename
6803811  221704 3419168 10444683 9f5f8b foo.static
```

This gives you the size of the [text segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) (also known as code segment), [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment), [block started by symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss).  dec is the size of the text, data and bss size added together.  hex is the same number in hexadecimal.